# App Engine can't connect to Cloud SQL: Connection refused

Tags: python, postgresql, google-app-engine, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql

I would love if anyone can please help me with the following:

### Summary

I'm on a newly created GCP project and I'm trying to connect from `App Engine` (a python app) to `Cloud SQL` (a postgresql instance). But I'm getting an error:

```
OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server on socket "/cloudsql/<project_id>:southamerica-east1:test-instance/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: Connection refused
```

#### The python app / App Engine (Standard environment)

The app is an API created with `FastAPI`. It uses `sqlmodel/sqlalchemy` for handling the database and `psycopg2-binary` as adapter. This is the code that connects to the database and create the tables:

```py
import sqlalchemy
from sqlmodel import create_engine

connection_name = "<project_id>:southamerica-east1:test-instance" # Here I omitted the real project id

url = sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL.create(
    drivername="postgresql+psycopg2",
    username="some-username",
    password="some-password",
    database="some-database-name",
    connection_name = connection_name,
    query={"host": "{}/{}".format("/cloudsql", connection_name)},
)
engine = create_engine(url)

def create_db_and_tables():
    SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

The strange thing is that, I've successfully deployed the same app in the past to `App Engine` (a few months ago, in another project and an older version of the app) and it was connecting to `Cloud SQL`. And according to me, I've used the same code for the connection, in both cases.

#### Expanded Error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: 
Connection refused
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket
 "/cloudsql/<project_id>:southamerica-east1:test-instance/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

#### Notes / Things that I have tried

- I'm able to connect to the `Cloud SQL` database from my local `pgAdmin 4`.
- If I remove the database part of the app, the app gets deployed to `App Engine` correctly.
- I've tried using `psycopg2` instead of `psycopg2-binary`.
- I've tried restarting/shutting down the cloud sql instance.
- I've tried using a different adapter, an async one (I don't this is the way though, because as I mentioned before I was able to deployed before using `psycopg2`)

Comment: In case you are wondering, if I print the value of `url`, this is what I get: `postgresql+psycopg2://some-username:some-password@/some-database-name?host=%2Fcloudsql%2F<project_id>%3Asouthamerica-east1%3Atest-instance`

Comment: Are you using App Engine Flex or App Engine Standard? Did you make sure to grant the service account Cloud SQL client permissions?

Comment: @kurtisvg I'm using the standard environment. I just added the `Cloud SQL Admin` role to App Engine's service account and I'm still getting the same error. The service account also has an "Editor" role. Should I add something else?

Comment: It should just need 'Cloud SQL connect' or higher in the project the CLoud SQL instance is in. Did you check the App engine logs to see if it has an error at the same time as your app?

Comment: @kurtisvg Thank you very much, that was the key to the solution. I was just looking at the logs through the command `gcloud app logs tail -s default`. I went directly to App Engine logs and I was having the following error: `Error 403: Cloud SQL Admin API has not been used in project before or it is disabled.` I enable that and is working now! Thanks

Comment: @JorgeAlvarado, please post your comment as an answer so that the community with similar questions will find this helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Summary

The problem was that I had the Cloud SQL Admin API disabled. I activated that an it worked.

## Details

I was only looking at the logs through my local console, using the command `gcloud app logs tail -s default` and the only error I was able to see with that,  was the one I posted in the original question.

But, following @kurtisvg advices, I checked App Engine logs directly through the GCP console and there, an other error appeared. The error was `Error 403: Cloud SQL Admin API has not been used in project before or it is disabled.`. I followed the instructions and it worked.

@kurtisvg thanks again!

Comment: This saved my day. The [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard#node.js) doesn't mention the need to enable "Cloud SQL Admin API" for this to work. Thanks.